# how to check python 3 on cmd when I have both python2 qnd python 3 installed on my system

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Please help ,me someone
how to check python 3 on cmd when I have both python2 qnd python 3 installed on my system

Comment: just type `python3` and enter the interpeter..

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1) Open command prompt or terminal.

2) type **python3**

Comment: hey I am trying to download python 3.5.6 for a project but cannot find the download exe file. Do you have any idea how to find it

Comment: are you trying to download it, or have you downloaded it prior, and finding the .exe?